# XmlpullparserException: Expected a quoted String(position:DOCDECL @1:62 in java.io.Inputstreamreader)

Tags: android, web-services

Code:

```
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, SOAP_METHOD_GETDATATBL);

            request.addProperty("TName", ttnm);
            request.addProperty("ColumnNameStr", "*");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL1, 60000);
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_GETDATATBL, envelope);

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
```

LogCat:

```
08-16 12:33:11.000: W/System.err(30741): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:62 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40912548) 
08-16 12:33:11.000: W/System.err(30741):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readQuotedId(KXmlParser.java:664)
08-16 12:33:11.000: W/System.err(30741):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readExternalId(KXmlParser.java:643)
08-16 12:33:11.000: W/System.err(30741):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readDoctype(KXmlParser.java:585)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:418)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2029)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at com.example.CommanDatabase.Parsing.getlogindata(Parsing.java:117)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at com.example.orecs.OrecsSlapeMain$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(OrecsSlapeMain.java:1333)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at com.example.orecs.OrecsSlapeMain$LoginAsyncTask.doInBackground(OrecsSlapeMain.java:1)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
08-16 12:33:11.010: W/System.err(30741):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-16 12:34:34.870: I/System.out(30927): Login Dailog Call
```

I got this error when I am getting data from server side. I dont know what is the problem with that. because when i used another web service, my code working well and when I change my web service then it give me this error. Main thing is that this web service's link is working in browser but not for android devices. It always throw this error. Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: where is your code & logcat error?

Comment: Check your SOAP_ACTION and show your code. as well as Error_Log

Comment: @CapDroid and Silent check my edited answer. and dont give downvotes..

Comment: @Segi what is your SOAP_ACTION and NAME_SPACE...?????

Comment: @Silent SOAP_ACTION is http://tempuri.org/GetDataTbl and NAME_SPACE is http://tempuri.org/

Comment: @Segi what is **URL1**?

Comment: @Cap its my URL of webservice.. i cant show here..

Comment: just explain me why you all give me downvotes.?? if you cant then dont downvote my question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem was in internet Security.. due to set Firewall in internet or Proxy, i couldn't connect that webservice which was in server side.

Answer (score 2):

In my case that error arose because of a change in URL from http to https. Hence, you may want to ensure you are getting a response code 200 before processing the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
    HttpTransportSE transporter;
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    SoapObject mSoapObject = null;
    String METHOD_NAME = getString(R.string.soap_method_authentication);
    try {

        mSoapObject = new SoapObject(getString(R.string.soap_namespace),METHOD_NAME);
        mSoapObject.addProperty("TName", "test");
        mSoapObject.addProperty("ColumnNameStr", "*");


        transporter = new HttpTransportSE(getString(R.string.soap_main_url));
        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(mSoapObject);
        transporter.call(getString(R.string.soap_namespace) + METHOD_NAME, envelope);


        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        System.out.println("Response : " + response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        mTextView.setText("Error...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**String.xml**

```
<string name="soap_main_url">your_main_url</string>
<string name="soap_namespace">http://tempuri.org/GetDataTbl/</string>
<string name="soap_method_authentication">GetDataTbl</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me, use

```
envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope (SoapEnvelope.VER12);
```

and it worked,