# XmlPullParserException: Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.InputStreamReader@21bd4488)

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

Facing the following issue :

Using the following code :

```
public void APIHit() {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.myutiitsl.com/PAN_WebService/services/PANWebService";
        String METHOD_NAME = "getPanDetails";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://www.myutiitsl.com/PAN_WebService/services/";
        String URL = "http://www.myutiitsl.com/PAN_WebService/services/PANWebService";

        try {
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("uname", "******");
            Request.addProperty("password", "******");
            Request.addProperty("pan", pancard);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerPropertyArrayList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headerPropertyArrayList.add(new HeaderProperty("Connection", "close"));
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope,headerPropertyArrayList); // error is coming on this line

            resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            Log.i(TAG, "Result Celsius: " + resultString);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            HashMap<String ,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            DefaultException.printStackTrace(ex,map,true,true);

        }
    }
```

This code was working till date since 4 months suddenly i am getting this error :

```
XmlPullParserException: Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.InputStreamReader@21bd4488) 
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readQuotedId(KXmlParser.java:670)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readExternalId(KXmlParser.java:649)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readDoctype(KXmlParser.java:591)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:421)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2048)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:96)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:189)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at com.app.aspirehomeloans.Fragments.SalesFragments.AadharVerification.APIHit(AadharVerification.java:590)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at com.app.aspirehomeloans.Fragments.SalesFragments.AadharVerification$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(AadharVerification.java:444)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at com.app.aspirehomeloans.Fragments.SalesFragments.AadharVerification$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(AadharVerification.java:430)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-11 12:46:18.726 1461-1651/com.app.aspirehomeloans W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am not able to understand the issue, as it was working till date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267386/xmlpullparserexception-expected-a-quoted-stringpositiondocdecl-162-in-java

Comment: @sasikumar I saw that question, but it is not a sequrity issue, as i tried to hit the soap webservice from SOAPUI application and i am getting proper respopnse